# How to plot 1-row dataframe as a barplot in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart, seaborn

I don't understand, what it wants from dataframe to be plotted. I have a dataframe

[image]

and trying to plot it. The goal is to have one bar per colum. But I can't.

I tried various combinations of this:

```
#df = df.transpose()
sns.barplot(y=df.index.values, x=df.values, order=df.index)
```

Comment: The plotting is done based on columns. You are imputing all the columns for X. It should just be one dimension.

Comment: Try to change this wide format data to long format to get only 2 columns. they can be visualized using barplot.

Comment: I was trying to transpose, it was giving data in rows, but the function didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this wide format to long format using `melt` function in pandas.

```
long_df = pd.melt(df)
sns.barplot(y = long_df.variable, x = long_df.value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Plot using seaborn.barplot

```
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns
    sales = {'Tony': 103,
     'Sally': 202,
     'Randy': 380,
     'Ellen': 101,
     'Fred': 82
    }

    #making dict to 1 row DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(sales, index=[0])

    #flattening the values to be compliant with 
    #barplot method of seaborn and columns of dataframe
    
    values = df.values.flatten()
    sns.barplot(x = df.columns,y=values)
```

The only problem with your data is just you need to flatten it to make it compatible and use the above arguments of barplot